# Python cross-platform listening for keypresses?

Tags: python, keyboard-events

I need to listen for certain keypresses in a python terminal program without pausing execution with `raw_input`. I've seen people use a few windows specific ways of listening for keystrokes and I've seen people use large modules like tkinter and pygame which I want to avoid.

Is there a lightweight module out there that does this cross platform (at least ubuntu, windows, mac)? or is there a way to use just the event system from tkinter, pygame, etc...?

If not, how should I approach tackling this? My first thought is to redirect stdin to another process and keep checking to see if it contains one of my event keys.

---

### edit

Thank you @unutbu for taking the time to mark this question that is 3 years old and successfully answered as a duplicate of another question whose answers do not apply to this question because I specifically asked about a non-blocking solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any cross-platform lightweight module that listens for keypresses. But here's a suggestion in case you want to implement something simple:

Check out this question on [getting a single keypress at a time](http://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time) in the Python FAQ. You could experiment a bit with blocking reads from `sys.stdin` and `threading`. But this may only work on Unix. On Windows, you can use [`msvcrt.kbhit`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit).

Combining the keypress recipe from the Python FAQ and the `msvcrt` module, the resulting `kbhit` function would go like this:

```
try:
    from msvcrt import kbhit
except ImportError:
    import termios, fcntl, sys, os
    def kbhit():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)
        oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)
        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    c = sys.stdin.read(1)
                    return True
                except IOError:
                    return False
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)
            fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
```

Comment: `def kbhit():
    ...
    return sys.stdin.read(1)`

Comment: +1 I was able to accomplish what I needed in this case based off of your answer. thanks.

Comment: -1 This does **not** contain something equivalent to the `msvcrt` module's `kbhit()` function which only tests if a key has been pressed or not. This is because it's based on code from the Python FAQ for _getting_ single keypresses one at a time. Your adaption does that when one is available and then throws the character read away, so it is lost.

Comment: What do you once you've imported kbhit? How do you use it?

Comment: EI capitan 10.11.3 (15D21), I got this error: termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: no
Keypresses are system-dependent.  They are interrupt-driven.  They one of the basic things built into most modern OSes.  They have different philosophies that can't be unified in a generic way without losing functionality.

you might try-
**termios** = unix, posix-style file-descriptor driven

**curses** = portal terminal-style handling (which is a specific console-based paradigm not generic)

Python wraps certain classes of input that might come from the keyboard: e.g., sys.stdin for console inupt.

But trying to get universal keyboard input is a very general problem that's inherently platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python module plataform, to get the current OS and then make a solution for each platform:

```
import platform
platform.platform()
'Linux-3.3.0-8.fc16.x86_64-x86_64-with-fedora-16-Verne'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can do it on Windows:

```
"""

    Display series of numbers in infinite loop
    Listen to key "s" to stop
    Only works on Windows because listening to keys
    is platform dependent

"""

# msvcrt is a windows specific native module
import msvcrt
import time

# asks whether a key has been acquired
def kbfunc():
    #this is boolean for whether the keyboard has bene hit
    x = msvcrt.kbhit()
    if x:
        #getch acquires the character encoded in binary ASCII
        ret = msvcrt.getch()
    else:
        ret = False
    return ret

#begin the counter
number = 1

#infinite loop
while True:

    #acquire the keyboard hit if exists
    x = kbfunc() 

    #if we got a keyboard hit
    if x != False and x.decode() == 's':
        #we got the key!
        #because x is a binary, we need to decode to string
        #use the decode() which is part of the binary object
        #by default, decodes via utf8
        #concatenation auto adds a space in between
        print ("STOPPING, KEY:", x.decode())
        #break loop
        break
    else:
        #prints the number
        print (number)
        #increment, there's no ++ in python
        number += 1
        #wait half a second
        time.sleep(0.5)
```