# Exit while loop by user hitting ENTER key

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a python newbie and have been asked to carry out some exercises using while and for loops. I have been asked to make a program loop until exit is requested by the user hitting `<Return>` only. So far I have:

```
User = raw_input('Enter <Carriage return> only to exit: ')
running = 1
while running == 1:
    Run my program
if User == # Not sure what to put here
    Break
else
    running == 1
```

I have tried: (as instructed in the exercise)

```
if User == <Carriage return>
```

and also

```
if User == <Return>
```

but this only results in invalid syntax.
Please could you advise me on how to do this in the simplest way possible. 
Thanks

Comment: Oh, `break` should be lowercase, too. And you need to indent more lines to go inside the loop.

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this page while (no pun) looking for something else. Here is what I use:

```
while True:
    i = input("Enter text (or Enter to quit): ")
    if not i:
        break
    print("Your input:", i)
print("While loop has exited")
```

Comment: Simple, effective, and pythonic.

Comment: Raises `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` in Python 2. Using `raw_input` may fix, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 17):

The exact thing you want ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22391379/3394391

```
import sys, select, os

i = 0
while True:
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print "I'm doing stuff. Press Enter to stop me!"
    print i
    if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
        line = raw_input()
        break
    i += 1
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Here is (I believe) the original source, which has further information about non-blocking stdin: https://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I suppose you are looking for a code that runs a loop until a key is pressed from the keyboard. Of course, the program shouldn't wait for the user all the time to enter it.

1. If you use `raw_input()` in python 2.7 or `input()` in python 3.0, The program waits for the user to press a key.
2. If you don't want the program to wait for the user to press a key but still want to run the code, then you got to do a little more complex thing where you need to use `kbhit()` function in [`msvcrt`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit) module.

Actually, there is a recipe in ActiveState where they addressed this issue. Please follow this [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146066-exiting-a-loop-with-a-single-key-press/)

I think the following links would also help you to understand in much better way.

1. [python cross platform listening for keypresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044073/python-cross-platform-listening-for-keypresses)
2. [How do I get a single keypress at a time](http://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time)
3. [Useful routines from the MS VC++ runtime](http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html#module-msvcrt)

I hope this helps you to get your job done.

Answer (score 2):

Use a print statement to see what `raw_input` returns when you hit `enter`. Then change your test to compare to that.

Comment: the print statement is blank so I have tried User == '' but still this line is highlighted as invalid syntax

Comment: raw_input will not capture <enter> or <return>

Answer (score 2):

This works for python 3.5 using parallel threading. You could easily adapt this to be sensitive to only a specific keystroke.

```
import time
import threading


# set global variable flag
flag = 1

def normal():
    global flag
    while flag==1:
        print('normal stuff')
        time.sleep(2)
        if flag==False:
            print('The while loop is now closing')

def get_input():
    global flag
    keystrk=input('Press a key \n')
    # thread doesn't continue until key is pressed
    print('You pressed: ', keystrk)
    flag=False
    print('flag is now:', flag)

n=threading.Thread(target=normal)
i=threading.Thread(target=get_input)
n.start()
i.start()
```

Comment: Some very minor nitpicking: `flag = 1` -> `flag = True`. `while flag==1` -> `while flag`. `if flag==False:` -> `if not flag:`. And you only have to state the `global` if you want to write to a variable, so you can remove `global flag` from `normal()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the variable User would look like when you just press Enter. I won't give you the full answer, but a tip: Fire an interpreter and try it out. It's not that hard ;) Notice that print's sep is '\n' by default (was that too much :o)

Comment: I tried to use a print statement to do this and the variable is blank so I tried User == '' but this results in invalid syntax as does User == '\n'

Comment: Why should you be doing `User == "`? " is invalid Syntax. I'll help you even a bit more (even though this is soooo obvious actually): `print repr(raw_input())` and just hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if repr(User) == repr(''):
    break
```

Comment: this line is still being highlighted as invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

a very simple solution would be, and I see you have said that you 
would like to see the simplest solution possible.
A prompt for the user to continue after halting a loop Etc.

```
raw_input("Press<enter> to continue")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input=input("ENTER SOME POSITIVE INTEGER : ")
if((not user_input) or (int(user_input)<=0)):    
   print("ENTER SOME POSITIVE INTEGER GREATER THAN ZERO") #print some info
   import sys        #import
   sys.exit(0)       #exit program 
'''
#(not user_input) checks if user has pressed enter key without entering  
# number.
#(int(user_input)<=0) checks if user has entered any number less than or 
#equal to zero.
'''
```

Comment: You need to provide some discussion explaining how your answer addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best and simplest answer. Use try and except calls.

```
x = randint(1,9)
guess = -1

print "Guess the number below 10:"
while guess != x:
    try:
        guess = int(raw_input("Guess: "))

        if guess < x:
            print "Guess higher."
        elif guess > x:
            print "Guess lower."
        else:
            print "Correct."
    except:
        print "You did not put any number."
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there. the easiest way to get this done would be to search for an empty variable, which is what you get when pressing enter at an input request. My code below is 3.5

```
running = 1
while running == 1:

    user = input(str('Enter <Carriage return> only to exit: '))

    if user == '':
        running = 0
    else:
        print('You had one job...')
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use u\000D. It is the CR in unicode.

Comment: I edited your post to reduce the impression that you only want to comment. If you indeed want to comment instead of actually answering please delete this and wait for your commenting privilege. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution (resembling the original) that works:

```
User = raw_input('Enter <Carriage return> only to exit: ')
while True:
    #Run my program
    print 'In the loop, User=%r' % (User, )

    # Check if the user asked to terminate the loop.
    if User == '':
        break

    # Give the user another chance to exit.
    User = raw_input('Enter <Carriage return> only to exit: ')
```

Note that the code in the original question has several issues:

1. The `if`/`else` is outside the while loop, so the loop will run forever.
2. The `else` is missing a colon.
3. In the else clause, there's a double-equal instead of equal. This doesn't perform an assignment, it is a useless comparison expression.
4. It doesn't need the running variable, since the `if` clause performs a `break`.

Answer (score -2):

If you want your user to press enter, then the raw_input() will return "", so compare the User with "":

```
User = raw_input('Press enter to exit...')
running = 1
while running == 1:
    Run your program
if User == "":
    break
else
    running == 1
```

Comment: I have attempted this but the 5th line is still highlighted as invalid syntax

Comment: You also need a `:` after the `else`, and `running == 1` is a boolean expression not an assignment.

Answer (score -2):

The following works from me:

```
i = '0'
while len(i) != 0:
    i = list(map(int, input(),split()))
```

Comment: Please explain your code, and what more does it bring that other answers do not.