# Exiting while loop by pressing enter without blocking. How can I improve this method?

Tags: python, loops, input, exit, enter

So I've been doing a little bit of reading up on how to exit a while loop by the user pressing the enter key and I've come up with the following:

```
import sys, select, os

switch = 1
i = 1
while switch == 1:
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print "I'm doing stuff. Press Enter to stop me!"
    print i
    while sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
        line = raw_input()
        if not line:
            print "Finished! =]"
            switch = 0
        else:
            print "Finished! =]"
            switch = 0
    i = i+1
```

Is there a way to tidy this up? In particular the "if not line" and the following "else" look messy. Can they be combined into one? A better alternative to using "switch"?

Initially if I typed a bunch of characters and then hit enter it didn't stop the loop. I would have to press enter again. The if not and else components are intended to set it up such that it would exit on the first press of enter.

Comment: Why not get rid of the `if`, as it does the same either way? Also, `while True` and `break` is neater than a flag

Comment: Does this actually work on Windows? The docs say that select.select only supports sockets on Windows: http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Comment: @Weeble I think this should work for Windows? http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146066-exiting-a-loop-with-a-single-key-press/ I'm coding on Ubuntu, personally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import sys, select, os

i = 0
while True:
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print "I'm doing stuff. Press Enter to stop me!"
    print i
    if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
        line = raw_input()
        break
    i += 1
```

You only need to check for the stdin being input once (since the first input will terminate the loop).  If the conditions line/not line have result for you, you can combine them to one if statement.  Then, with only one `while` statement being used, you can now use `break` instead of setting a flag.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you!

Comment: Actually in hindsight, I realize you don't even need ```if line or not line```... it's always True.

Comment: You do need the raw_input() call though, because if the user inputs anything besides Enter and then presses Enter, it throws a NameError.

Comment: If I had enough rep I would upvote the hell out of your solution. I hope others can benefit from this!

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Here is (I believe) the original source, which has further information about non-blocking stdin: https://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/