# Python: Output while waiting for input

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.x

So I currently have a thread that is outputting, and I need a way to handle input while still allowing output from the thread in the meantime.

Currently I have something like this

```
def thread_func():
    while True:
        print("Information")

threading.Thread(target=thread_func).start()

while True:
    command = raw_input("Enter a command:")
    #dostuff with command
```

My issue now is that my thread isn't printing anything.  Or if it is it isn't showing up

**Edit:**

Found a solution here
[Exiting while loop by pressing enter without blocking. How can I improve this method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391134/exiting-while-loop-by-pressing-enter-without-blocking-how-can-i-improve-this-me/22391379#22391379)

Comment: I cannot duplicate this behavior. In fact, when I run this same code in Python2 it prints `"Information"` so quickly I'm unable to enter the command. Can you be more specific in the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: You're right, that does run.  I was trying to simplify the code because it's kinda complicated and very specific to what I'm working on.  Basically in the thread I'm looping over a stream and I guess for some reason that's causing the issue.  I ended up fixing the problem by looking at the answer supplied here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391134/exiting-while-loop-by-pressing-enter-without-blocking-how-can-i-improve-this-me/22391379#22391379

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391134/exiting-while-loop-by-pressing-enter-without-blocking-how-can-i-improve-this-me/22391379#22391379 The answer to this is what I used to fix my program

Comment: Awesome I'm glad it's working! I'm closing this question as a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score -2):

You want to use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). New input will go into the back of the queue, and work will be started from the front.

Comment: It's not clear how a queue would be implemented to solve his problem.