# How to output while waiting for a character input in Python 3?

Tags: python

I want to make a timer which requiers space press to stop it. I also want to print out how much time has passed since the start of the loop. I tried this:

```py
import msvcrt
import time

print("Press space")
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    # print how much time has passed
    print(start_time - time.time(), end='\r')

    # break the loop if space btn was pressed
    if msvcrt.getch() == b" ":
        break
```

But the problem is that the time passed will be printed only if I pressed a key, and I want it to print out continuesly. I tried this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22391379/12132452, but because it was python 2, i kept getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Projects/Python/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
OSError: [WinError 10093] Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
import sys
import keyboard
import time

print("Press space")
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    try:

        print(start_time - time.time(), end='\r')
        if keyboard.is_pressed('SPACE'):
            print("\nyou pressed SPACE, exiting...")
            sys.exit()
    except:
        break
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'

Comment: Install it with  python -m pip install keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was answered, but here is another way of doing it in pygame:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Timer')

start_time = time.time()

def main():
    running = True
    fps = 60
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    while running:
        clock.tick(fps)


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            print(time.time() - start_time)
            running = False
        
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Also, to install pygame open a terminal and type:

```
python -m pip install pygame==1.9.6
```