# Integers, should be entered one per line, how to make 'hit return when done'?

Tags: python

```
nums = []

num = 0
valid_list = []
while num !=  '':
    num = input('Enter numbers :')
    nums.append(num)
nums2 = [(nums[i]) for i in range(0,len(nums))]
for i in range(len(nums2)):
    if int(nums2[i]) < 101 and int(nums2[i]) > 0:
        valid_list.append(nums2[i])

print(valid_list)
```

Sorry dont really know how to ask question corectly, but i hope those who get my idea will help, Thanks. So i am tryed to make program wich fills list with integers entered by user, than chech if they fit 1-101 and if they fit put those number in valid_list, The problem is while num !=  '':  (BTW inters must be entered one by one, and it must stop when return is hited)

Comment: Rather than just put random words in the tags, it would help immensely if you would add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255463/exit-while-loop-by-user-hitting-enter-key

Comment: In the line with nums2 = ...: nums2 will be equal to nums.

Answer (score 0):

Without having actually tested it, I think this is what you want:

```
nums = []

num = 0
valid_list = []

while true:
    num = input('Enter numbers :')

    if not num:
        break

    nums.append(num)

nums2 = [(nums[i]) for i in range(0,len(nums))]

for i in range(len(nums2)):
    if int(nums2[i]) < 101 and int(nums2[i]) > 0:
        valid_list.append(nums2[i])

print(valid_list)
```

From [Python 'If not' syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739555/python-if-not-syntax) the `if not num` syntax is explained as executing if num is any kind of zero or empty container, or False.