# Keyboard Strokes Python

Tags: python

How does one apply a keystroke to console code without using Pygame's event checking system.  I would prefer something that internalizes the loop and only requires a main running loop.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: This post has a variety of answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Python myself, but when I looked into the tkinter GUI framework I came across a way to make keystrokes perform commands.

Here's the detailed page regarding keyboard strokes, although you probably should read from earlier in the tutorial to get a hang on things:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/events.html#key-names

Here's a more detailed example:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Also, this thread might be a different useful way to go about it:
[Python cross-platform listening for keypresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044073/python-cross-platform-listening-for-keypresses)