# Detect keyboard presses

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a program that needs to be able to detect keyboard presses outside of the window. How would I be able to do something like the following:

```
while True:
    if getKey() == w:
        #Do a thing
    if getKey() == a:
        #Do a different thing
```

Comment: You can use getch()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python

Comment: This question doesn't already have an anwser. The above answer ONLY works in command console, he's looking for something to work outside of the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "outside of the window" actually means "outside of the console" you could try something like the following to append your keyword events to an output file.

```
import win32api 
import sys
import pythoncom, pyHook

buffer = ''
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
if event.Ascii == 5: 
  sys.exit() 
if event.Ascii != 0 or 8: 
  f = open ('c:\\output.txt', 'a') 
  keylogs = chr(event.Ascii) 
if event.Ascii == 13: 
  keylogs = keylogs + '\n' 
  f.write(keylogs) 
  f.close() 
while True:
  hm = pyHook.HookManager() 
  hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent 
  hm.HookKeyboard() 
  pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

http://antihackingtutorials.blogspot.de/2012/06/in-this-tutorial-we-will-show-you-how.html