# Interrupt python script with a specific key on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I'm trying to have a loop which increments and prints a value. While it's running I would like to press a key (eg. space or shift) and have it print that the key was pressed. Below is example code of what I would like.

```
def space():
    print 'You pressed space'    

def shift():
    print 'You pressed shift'

x = 0
while True:    
    print(x)
    #if space is pressed
    space()
    #if shift is pressed    
    shift()
    x = x + 1;
    time.sleep(1)
```

EDIT: Here is an example output

```
0
1
2
You pressed shift
3
4
5
You pressed space
6
7
.
.
.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand that post.

Comment: @BadProgrammer. Then why do you expect to be able to understand a similar post made here? The thing with the code snippets in the other question is that you can copy-and-paste them into your program and just use them as-is. I would recommend http://stackoverflow.com/a/21659588/2988730 as it is probably the simplest one to understand up-front. The meat of the code is the same as for the other ones.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, what I don't understand is that the post referenced by Padraic was to catch a character. I do not understand how I can use a shift or space key instead of a character. Sorry, I was a bit vague with my previous comment.

Comment: @turkus found a question that may help you more in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11918999/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist I will look into it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with modified answer form here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

and for only space and enter:

```
import contextlib
import sys
import termios
import time


@contextlib.contextmanager
def raw_mode(file):
    old_attrs = termios.tcgetattr(file.fileno())
    new_attrs = old_attrs[:]
    new_attrs[3] = new_attrs[3] & ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON)
    try:
        termios.tcsetattr(file.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, new_attrs)
        yield
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(file.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, old_attrs)


def space(ch):
    if ord(ch) == 32:
        print 'You pressed space'

def enter(ch):
    if ord(ch) == 10:
        print 'You pressed enter'


def main():
    print 'exit with ^C or ^D'
    with raw_mode(sys.stdin):
        try:
            x = 0
            while True:
                print(x)
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
                space(ch)
                enter(ch)
                x = x + 1;
                time.sleep(1)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Proper form would be to mark this question as a duplicate, not copy-and-paste someone else's answer here.

Comment: I saw this habbit in couple of answers and nobody was complaining, so I just followed. Furthermore, it's not a duplicate, this answer is about something else: ```I'm trying to have a loop which increments and prints a value. While it's running I would like to press a key (eg. space or shift) and have it print that the key was pressed.```

Comment: Sure, now I know :) Thanks, could you remove downvote and I won't do it again?

Comment: XY problem. Slightly different phrasing does not mean that the question is really different.

Comment: @MadPhysicist So if you downvoting, you can also downvote previous answer, because of duplicated answer from the same link.

Comment: @turkus I gave you an up vote because you helped without being a jerk. Thanks!

Comment: I made a 1-word edit to allow me to remove my downvote.

Comment: @turkus What I am stuck on is I need the while loop to continue to print as it increments and then if I press something to have the interrupt printed. However, the answer you provided essentially just waits until a key is pressed. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @BadProgrammer so exit running script?

Comment: @turkus No, I do not want the running script to be exited. I just want it to print that I pressed the key inside of the loop and then for the loop to continue. Does that make sense?

Comment: @BadProgrammer so script will still listen your keyboard and running but timer will "stop"? And doesn't appear?

Comment: @turkus the script will be increment and print a counter every second. However, it will be listening for an input from the keyboard and if space or shift is pressed, then it will print that the key was pressed as it continues to increment the counter. Example output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 Space was pressed 7 8 9 Shift was pressed 10 11 12 13 14 15 16...

Comment: Now I know what about you're talking about :) Working on.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on windows, check out [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/msvcrt.html):

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    x += 1
    sleep(x)
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        print "You pressed: %s" % msvcrt.getch()
```

Comment: OP wants `if` before `sleep`, but aside from that, nice.

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Linux :/ is there a Unix equivalent?

Comment: Hi BadProgrammer, yes there is, it's curses: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

But it's much, much more involved. I don't know it well enough to post a short snippet.

Comment: Thanks @DaveMcPhee, I looked at curses and it looks a lot more complicated than msvcrt. Is it possible for someone to post code snippet example?

Comment: Use select. Working on answer now.