# How to detect keyboard input independently of the open window Python

Tags: python, input, keyboard, window, any

I was wondering if there was a way to detect a pressed key with python independently of the window that is open. I tried with ord(getch()) but it works only if you have the cmd open. I would like it to work even if I was, for instance, browsing on Google Chrome.

Comment: Sounds like your making a key logger. Search for `python keylogger`

Comment: This seems a duplicate to me. I believe [pynput](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python/43106497#43106497) is what you like to use.

Answer (score 0):

Three years later... But here goes... Installing the package `pip install keyboard` and use the is_pressed method. I've tested this on Windows, can't confirm whether or not it works on Linux/MacOS.

```
import keyboard
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        print('a')
```