# How can I edit an inputed text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m building a command line application with python, and I Need to be able to print something, then the user edit it and return it to me

I know that Input() doesn’t fit to my case because the user can’t modify the text you give him.
Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: You'd probably need to use a full UI like with Tkinter, or use a library like Curses. Text manipulation in plain consoles is fairly limited.

Comment: this is rather system issue, as I know console does not support that (unless I am wrong) so you need to run another app where user may enter data into input control

Comment: But take exemple of vim, the user can modify the text that is in vim

Comment: vim is an application written in c, it constructs it's windows in c, so it's a bit irrelevant since you are writing in python. (You could use c in python, but I think it's a bit more complex than other available solutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that one way to do this is by using a **keyboard input listener** - this way you can figure out exactly what the user is doing (all characters being pressed, as well as backspace) and print the edited text.

You can have a look at this answer, which gives examples of how to achieve this in linux/windows: [Key Listeners in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python).

If you are looking for a User Interface (not proper command line), you can use Tkinter do display a text box in which the user can input it's data.

An example (based on https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm):

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

e = Entry(master, width=500)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()

def callback():
    print e.get()

b = Button(master, text="get", width=50, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`readline` is the name of the system that lets the user edit terminal input (in a micro-Emacs environment by default).  You can use [`readline.insert_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#readline.insert_text) to supply text to edit.  One supported way of doing this is to arrange to call it via `set_pre_input_hook` before calling `input`.

Answer (score 0):

So, as Anatoly said, I’m going to learn curse, because I will need other things curse can do. Thank you for everyone which has responded. I will also use read line.insert_text

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

if you are using windows use `os.system('cls')` :)