# How to run a function (in Python) when user presses a specific key?

Tags: python, msvcrt, getch

I tried this

```
from msvcrt import getch

while True:
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 27: #ESC
        print("You pressed ESC")
    elif key == 13: #Enter
        print("You pressed key ENTER")
```

but it works only in terminal, i want to run a function whenever user presses the key, even his curser in not in terminal, Please help...
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Key Listeners in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python)

Comment: Unfortunately No, Actually, i want to run a function whenever user presses a key, for example, on windows when we press "window" key it opens th start menu even if the user is using any software on the computer

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not the easiest thing if you want to get it working correctly. If you have a window/widget in focus, using Qt and a QKeyEvent would be the easiest solution. However, if you want your input to be read globally/in other applications and not just from the terminal, you'll need to do something a bit more involved:

[How to generate keyboard events in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python)