# Global Keybindings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, key-bindings

Can we make some global keybindings with python?

I mean when I'm in another application or game if I press `X` the code do something.
I searched for that but only found for Ubuntu or Linux...
But I want something for Windows and Python3.x.

---

Solution: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#global-hotkeys

Comment: You can convert your script into an executable exe and use winhotkey to map it to a shortcut key combination.

Comment: Thanks @NALIN_yo. this is a good idea. I don't need to convert my script to an exe file. I can create `.bat` files who run my scripts. but I want to use my own app not winhotkey or etc for Keybinding.

Comment: You can use pynput for detecting hotkeys. This documentation can help: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#global-hotkeys

Comment: Have you tried the tutorial above @PokerFaCe ?

Comment: Yes. that solved my problem. I added another answer and I said it. but deleted. thanks. @NALIN_yo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I found, which works well.
using the module pynput. It will listen to key press globally.
I found the answer here [stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python)

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))
        
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
```