# OS X Python: How to capture USB scanner output masquerading as keyboard?

Tags: python, macos

A USB scanner, which presents as a keyboard is at:

```
lsusb | grep -i scanner
Bus 250 Device 005: ID 0c2e:9a6c 0c2e Metrologic Scanner
```

Is there an example of python script that can record the 'keystrokes' from the ***scanner only*** into a variable for further parsing? Example or links to examples are appreciated: thank you

In Unix, evdev would handle these events, however, this mechanism is absent in OS X.

[This excerpt was from another posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865446/can-i-use-python-to-capture-keyboard-and-mouse-events-in-osx):

Code from http://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import termios, fcntl, sys, os

fd = sys.stdin.fileno()

oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)

oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

try:
    while 1:
        try:
            c = sys.stdin.read(1)
            print "Got character", repr(c)
        except IOError: pass
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
```

One more solution 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python](http://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time)

Comment: If it behaves as standard input, have you tried `input()`?

Comment: No because, I would like to direct only 'keystrokes' from the scanner to the variable.

Comment: Wouldn't you just read from stdin?  I don't know anything about python, but if it's a keyboard...

Comment: Good question.  I have the scanner performing well on Ubuntu with Python.  I am attempting to port it for OSX.