# Key strokes in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am wanting to create a pseudo psychological program with Python3, where I need to record the keystrokes of users and when they were pressed to compare how quickly they completed each task. Any suggestions as to how I could proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options of modules for getting key events from the keyboard:

1. [Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882985/capture-keystrokes-for-a-game-python) (Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame))
2. [Pykeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/)
3. [Tkinter](http://www.ehow.com/how_12150530_create-keylogger-using-python.html)

The one you'll use depends on your individual needs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at them.